# How to verify native applications with OAuth from different sub-domains for google cloud verification?

Tags: java, oauth, gmail, native, google-workspace

I am using OAuth 2 to get permissions from my users .it has restricted api's too.Each user is using each sub-domain.Now while getting permission it's showing my app is disabled.How can i get my app verified?The main problem is each user has a sub-domain for themselves.Can anyone provide a solution other than the google cloud platform documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Read this documentation [1] to check if you're seeing an error prompting you to request app verification. This FAQ [2] has even more information in case you need to request app verification.

[1] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

[2] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en